# Linux clipboard manager allowing to ignore selected programs

Tags: linux, clipboard

I'm looking for a clipboard manager for Linux that has an ability to exclude applications, for instance password managers.

Something like Ditto in Windows would be perfect, with search and images etc. but that's all optional, program exclusion is the only must-have.